# Javascript currying: why does one closure scope example work, but another doesn't?

Tags: javascript, closures, currying, partial-application

I'm trying to understand the video "Understanding Function Currying" on Vimeo ( http://vimeo.com/41238143 but not necessary to view it in order to understand this question).

### The example I understand

Early in the video, We’re told that there’s a problem with this code:

[image]

The problem with this code: the use of callback on line 11 and 14 won’t work because it’s out of scope — *onSuccess* exists in the *buildCRUD* scope, not the *create* scope. (I'll call this the "callback example".)

OK, that makes sense to me. Solutions are considered including using a single class variable (I know this terminology is off because javascript doesn't have classes, but you know what I mean).

### The example I don't understand

Here's where I'm confused. At the end of the video, we're told that this code for a different part of the function will work. (Notice the *"className"* variable parameter; I'll call this the "className example".)

(Sorry, I cut off the line that says "var ...", just trust me that it's up there and *createFn*, *getFn*, etc. are all being declared as part of a long "var" line.)

[image]

As you can see, the implementation of these functions such as *createFn* do use the *className* variable, though it wasn't passed into the function as a parameter.

[image]

Here's my question: **why is *className* in scope inside *createFn*?** It seems to me that it’s no more in the *forClass* scope than *onSuccess* was in the create scope.

Does this have something to do with...

- the fact that the function in the callback example is never being assigned as a variable inside the create function context, only called?
- the callback example using promises?

Comment: Please post code that is copy&executable. Not screenshots.

Comment: And blurry ones at that. Presumably there's a link associated with the video for the code. Get the code, trim it down to what relates to your question, and post that.

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me (or there's a second `className` declaration where we don't see it). Notice that `onSuccess` *is* in `create`'s scope, but `callback` is not in `onSuccess`' scope. No, this has nothing to do with promises.

Comment: Raptor - thanks, good idea, asking now. Bergi and T.J. Crowder -- yeah, that could improve it, but I'm not asking "what should i do?" which would require code-heavy answers. I'm asking "what principle is at play here?" so that I can read more about that.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies everyone. The Vimeo recording may have had some errors.

To demonstrate a working solution, I created a working version of the Book CRUD service to demonstrate Partial Applications in JavaScript... used within an AngularJS application.

```
getFn = function (objectId, callback) {

      // Simulate $http to get book information for
      // specified ID.

      var deferred = $q.defer(),
          book = {
            url : buildRequestURL(objectId),
            title : "Learn to use Javascript Partial Applications"                
            author: "Thomas Burleson"
          },
          notifyFn = onSuccess(callback);


      $timeout(function() {
        notifyFn( book );
        deferred.resolve( book );
      });

      return deferred.promise;
}
```

@see [Full Source & Live CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/ThomasBurleson/pen/vEKPqB)